# ASROCK 970 Extreme4 with x2 r9 290, no display on second monitor

Tags: windows-7, drivers, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, motherboard

I have 2 gigabyte r9 290 video cards. Each of them has a monitor attached to it.
Each only seems to work when I plug them into the PCIE2 slot. 
When I boot up windows 7, it only recognises the monitor attached to PCIE2, no matter which card I try. So I know the VGA cards are ok as I have tested them individually on PCIE2.
Windows 7 can see the 2 r9 290 cards in device properties, but when I right click desktop and go to display resolution only the monitor attached to the graphics card in PCIE2 is shown. I cant put my desktop up on 2 monitors. It only shows 1 monitor.

I will say that I did have 2 monitors for about 1 second, then both monitors blinked, then I only had one displaying the desktop. Each time I unistall and re-install the AMD catalyst drivers its seems to do this.

Are there any motherboard or windows settings I should be trying to get this working?

Im running windows 7 ultimate SP1, AMD 13.12 catalyst drivers, 1200w power supply

Thanks

Comment: Ensure CrossFire is disabled.

Comment: Thanks techie007. That fixed it. If you make it an answer rather than I comment I can accept it.